# Breaking an integer, representing position, into parts and back again

Tags: c++, math

I'm working with some hardware that represent the absolute position of a motor, using an unsigned integer. Specs tells me that one digit represents 100nm.

A value of 100,000 is then <=> 10mm, as 100,000 x 100 == 10,000,000 nm <=> 10mm.

For a user to have fine control of the motor, working with such large numbers is not practical. So I'm presenting the number, using its mm, um and nm parts. I can get those as

```
//Input number x 100 -> value in nm
unsigned int nmVal = input * 100;
unsigned int mmValue = (nmVal / 10000000 % 10) * 10  + (nmVal / 1000000 % 10);
unsigned int umValue = (nmVal / 100000 % 10) * 100 + (nmVal / 10000 % 10) * 10 + 
(nmVal / 1000 % 10);
unsigned int nm = (nmVal / 100 % 10) * 100;
```

And I can present those in a UI as mmValue + umValue + nmValue in three edit boxes.

The user can then easily modify the nm part without worrying about the other parts.

The question is, how to go the other way, to the integer representing the position, from the 'parts', *without* using a double??

If I just add the numbers, i.e.

```
int position = mmVal * 1e-3 + umVal*1e-6 + nmVal*1e-9
```

the variable position will be zero.

Comment: Some friendly advice: for something like this, you might want to use `int64_t` instead of `int`. You'll thank me later when you aren't suddenly dealing with overflows in your code!

Comment: @Xirema Or even better `uint64_t` since I don't see a requirement to represent negative values.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Generally speaking, you shouldn't use unsigned integers to represent "amounts" unless that last bit of range is absolutely crucial. And to be honest, it's not clear to me that the OP's use case is one where there's absolutely no need for negative numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. As I'm dealing with a position, I'll make it unsigned. The max position will only be ~100000 however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the other way around:

`position_t nmPos = mmVal * 1e6 + umVal * 1e3 + nmVal;`

Comment: That was simple! I also  need to divide the nmPos number with 100, as to get it into the representation the hardware wants it. Thanks!